# How can I refresh every five minutes my Python File in Django

Tags: python, django

How can I refresh my python file in every five minutes in django while running because every hour the data I'm webscraping is changing and I need to change the value of the variable?

Comment: Is it possible to restart the server every five minutes in django? and how?

Comment: Yes it's possible but probably not the most effective method to achieve your desired goal here. Where is your data stored and in which format?

Comment: source = "google.com-this-is-just-example"
.
.
.
.
world_recovered = (soup.find("div", {"class": "fNm5wd gZvxhb"})).text
world_recovered = ''.join(filter(lambda i: i.isalpha()==False, world_recovered))

world_deaths = (soup.find("div", {"class": "fNm5wd ckqIZ"})).text
world_deaths = ''.join(filter(lambda i: i.isalpha()==False, world_deaths))



def home(request):
 context = {
 'world_death':world_deaths,
 'world_recovers': world_recovered,
 'world_confirms': world_confirmed,
 'total': confirmed,
 'recovered' : recovered,
 'deaths': deaths
 }

Comment: After i use web scrape and store the value in a variable, I will pass it down to a function

Answer (score 0):

You need is a task that runs periodically and a cron job solve that. I recomment to you take a look to [django cron](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Celerity](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), both are excelent options to create scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using database like sqlite3 is better solution than restart django(web service) per hours.

You can store some datas in database and django can get them like using variables.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is that you're fetching the data at the start of the application and keeping it in memory. I see 2 possible better methods:

- move the data scraping code to your view function. This means you'll re-scrape on every call ensuring you'll always have the freshest data but at the cost of speed (the time it takes to make the request to your target url).
- better yet: same as above except you cache the results locally. This could also be kept in memory (although I'd use a file or database if you're running multiple django app instances to ensure they're all using the same data). With the least amount of change to what you have already, an in memory cache could be achieved with simply adding a timestamp variable that gets the current time on each fetch. If last fetch was more than X minutes ago: refetch your data.